# Unable to set GCP Cloud CDN 'stripQuery': false error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I have created a Cloud CDN for my backend Cloud Run service (next.js app) with below configurations:

Path matcher (matches, actions and services):

```yaml
defaultService: projects/<project-name>/global/backendServices/custom-domains-stage-my-domain-com-stage-supplyz-com-49a4-be
name: stage-my-domain-com
pathRules:
- paths:
  - /*
  service: projects/<project-name>/global/backendServices/custom-domains-stage-my-domain-com-stage-my-domain-com-49a4-be
```

But getting an below error:

`Invalid value for field 'resource.defaultUrlRedirect': '{ "stripQuery": true}'. A default redirect can only be specified for a url map if it neither specifies a default service nor a default route action`